# iOS: Is it necessary to remove Firebase observers?

Tags: ios, firebase

Why should I remove firebase references observers? I'm ok if all references get observed as long as the app is running. I'm not sure if references will still be observed after the user leaves the app, but if memory is only consumed while the user is using the app, why bother remove the observers? Especially if the data is mostly light weight texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case is not what can happen if the user leaves the app, after it's closed/killed it'll not be observed anymore. Neither is a problem because of CPU or internet usage, since you'll get light weight texts. The case is what can happen if the user is using the app and an observable is fired.

Let's say that in your app's home page you'll have an observable sending the user to a specific page if a value on the user's node changes, and if in the middle of the usage this value changes the user may be redirected to another page without knowing what happened, so bad UX.

Something that happened to me was leaving observables and them i signed out of my account, my app broke because there was no user connected, therefore i wasn't able to observe a node where i needed to be authenticated to query a value.

So that's why you should remove every observable as you go off a page or when quiting the app or signing out, because it can give the user some errors or uncommom behaviours that'll make them think that the app is broken or is not a good app.

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Yea right, changing accounts could possibly cause some problems, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked into firebase documentation and there is no clear info about it.

There are several snippets saying that is a good practice to remove them on the opposite method you created them.
If you create them on `onCreate`, remove them on `onDestroy`. If you created them on `viewWillAppear`, remove them on `viewWillDisappear`.

In my experience I found out that is less cpu demanding to just leave them around if they are not firing very often. I have several observers on my app it's less cpu intensive to just quit the app than to remove them.